# In Ubuntu 12.04, how do you tell saslauthd to use getpwent instead of PAM?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, postfix

I have a fresh install, upgrading from ancient Ubuntu 8.x, and I just can't figure out where this setting is supposed to be in Ubuntu 12.04. Please help! Thanks